# In CloudWatch Metrics Insights, is it possible to graph metrics grouped by task instance or instance ID?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm running a `my-api-service-TEST` container in amazon ECS. The container contains two running task instances of `my-api-service`.
Currently, when graphing `CPUUtilization Max` I get an aggregation of both instances in the one graph.
Is it possible to display each instance's CPU usage separately? So I get a graph for each task running in that container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metrics available are all aggregated for ECS container. For deeper analysis on the metrics data, we can use CloudWatch Logs Insights queries.

For example:

```
stats avg(CpuUtilized) as CPU, avg(MemoryUtilized) as Mem by TaskId
| filter Type="Task"
| sort Mem, CPU desc
```

Please refer this [AWS forum post](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-container-insights-ecs) for more details. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please note that you have to enable ECS Container Insights before this level of detail is available. Container Insights incurs an added cost.

Comment: This works, thanks! Perhaps you can help me with this next query too if you have time?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76761680/how-can-i-organise-the-output-of-my-cloudwatch-insights-query

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable [ECS CloudWatch Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-container-insights.html) to get per-task and per-container metrics. This incurs an additional cost.