# How can I organise the output of my CloudWatch Insights query?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have the following Log insights query that I'm using in CloudWatch to extract memory/cpu related stats:

```
stats avg(MemoryUtilized) as MemoryUsed, avg(CpuUtilized) as CpuUsed by TaskDefinitionFamily, TaskId, MemoryReserved, CpuReserved, Timestamp
| filter Type="Task" and TaskDefinitionFamily="auth-customer-TEST"
| sort Timestamp, TaskDefinition, TaskId desc
| limit 2
```

It outputs the following:

| TaskDefinitionFamily | TaskId | MemoryReserved | CpuReserved | Timestamp | MemoryUsed | CpuUsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my-service | 901abb3daadd49c6983f3c6431fd33b8 | 1024 | 256.0 | 1690275900000 | 322 | 1.6687 |
| my-service | 9c831a65724e4b90ab2c4366954ac392 | 1024 | 256.0 | 1690275900000 | 295 | 1.1168 |

This is all good. However, I don't understand how I can order the columns.
I would like the `MemoryUsed` and `MemoryReserved` to be beside each other, the same for the CPU stats. Also, I'd like to remove the `Timestamp`.
I thought I could query and sort by `Timestamp` without specifying it in the first line, but I get different results if I do that.
Alternatively, is it possible to display the timestamp as a human readable date/time, or at least move it to the end of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this query?

```
stats avg(MemoryUtilized) as MemoryUsed, MemoryReserved, avg(CpuUtilized) as CpuUsed by TaskDefinitionFamily, CpuReserved, TaskId, fromMillis(Timestamp) as DateTime
| filter Type="Task" and TaskDefinitionFamily="auth-customer-TEST"
| sort Timestamp, TaskDefinition, TaskId desc
| limit 2
```

Please try for more datetime functions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-operations-functions.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-datetime).

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the date, but when I have the MemoryReserved on that side of the `by` statement, MemoryReserved is blank in the results. If it's on the other side of `by` then it's populated.

Comment: If I wrap it in an `avg(MemoryReserved)` then it returns the correct result. I'll do that.

Comment: Ok great. Could you mark my answer as accepted since it fixes the original problem?